How to co-relate (constrain) two parameters of a function, such that checking the value of one will constrain the other in the function body?
This question is related, <edit> and the answer there actually solves this question. But if you want to constrain the field values of an object, check this out</edit> but
a) I only care about string union types and
b) I care about the type inference within the function body, not (only) the outside view.
Given these types + function
type A = "a_1" | "a_2"

type B = "b_1" | "b_2"

function foo<T extends A> (a: T, b: T extends "a_1" ? "b_1" : "b_2") {
}

... TypeScript neatly type checks calls of foo:
// these two error:
foo2("a_2", "b_1")
foo2("a_1", "b_2")
// these two compile
foo2("a_1", "b_1")
foo2("a_2", "b_2")

But: Within the function body, even when a is checked, b's infered type doesn't follow suit:
function foo<T extends A> (a: T, b: T extends "a_1" ? "b_1" : "b_2") {
    if (a == "a_1") {
        let bar: "b_1" = b
        // ^ fails with Type "b_1" | "b_2" is not assignable to type "b_1
    }
}

Is there a way to have TypeScript recognize the link?

You can use a destructured discriminated union as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

Indeed, this solves the problem I posted. I've edited the question, it can be closed as a duplicate.
